# PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials always returns FALSE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I have an MVC application that needs to login and verify a user against Active Directory.  I am using the `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` method but always get a authentication of `false`.

Connecting to the Server is fine. The problem seems to occur in the `ValidateCredentials`.

Here is my code:

```
public static bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd) {
    bool IsAuthenticated = false;

    try {
        PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = 
            new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, "DC=c1w,DC=com");

        username = "c1w\\" + username;

        IsAuthenticated = insPrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, pwd);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Rethrow this exception
        ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Exception Policy");
    }

    return IsAuthenticated;
}
```

Anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see where you initializes the "pwd" variable
Maybe you should use [ContextOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contextoptions.aspx) in this method to specify exactly the reqired behaviour. Sorry for too broad response but there is no much details in your question

Comment: Editted the question to include the entire method.  Will try the ContextOption suggestion.  Thank you.

Comment: B-Rain,
The ContextOption reference pointed me in the right direction.  Ended up using the ContextOptions.Negotiate on my call to AD and ContextOptions.SimpleBind on the validate credentials.  Simple Bind will work for me since the site will be SSL Secured.  
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Upvoted both the question and the answer because this helped me in my situation as well.  In my case, my dev machine (where login works without context specified) is in the secured zone on the network, but the web server (where login doesn't work without context specified) is in the DMZ.  I used the same configuration as @Billy Logan - Negotiate on the call to AD and SimpleBind on the validate call.

Comment: So what did you use? ContextOptions.Negotiate or ContextOptions.SimpleBind?

Comment: If you use ContextOptions.Simplebind, be aware that the password may be sent in clear text over the wire.

Answer (score 20):

Here's how `ValidateCredentials(string, string)` works: First, it tries to authenticate with the `Negotiate`, `Signing`, and `Sealing` context options. If this fails, it tries again with `SimpleBind` and `SecureSocketLayer`.

The problem is that the NT4 (AKA "legacy", AKA "down-level name") format (`DOMAIN\UserName`, or more correctly, `NetBiosName\SamAccountName`) doesn't work with Negotiate. But it does work with SimpleBind.

So what's probably happening when calling the 2-parameter `ValidateCredentials()` method, is that it first fails using Negotiate because it doesn't like the NT4 format, and then fails again when using simple bind.

During my own testing, I've found that the reason why it fails even after falling back to using simple bind is that it's not only using SimpleBind. It's using `SimpleBind` plus `SecureSocketLayer`. This means that it will still fail if the Active Directory server isn't set up correctly to use SSL (a common scenario for test environments).

As was mentioned in one of the comments, you NEVER, NEVER want to use `SimpleBind` by itself (without `SecureSocketLayer`), otherwise your passwords are sent over the network in plain text.

In the wild, I've seen that some Active Directory systems don't allow the use of simple binds at all, so you must make it work with Negotiate.

I've found 2 ways to deal with this problem:

1) If everything is happening on the same domain, you should be able to call `ValidateCredentials` with only the username (SAM account name), leaving out the "DOMAIN\" part. Then, it will work properly the first time with Negotiate.

2) If the domain part is important because there may be multiple domains involved (i.e. `Domain1\UserA` and `Domain2\UserA` are different people), then it gets a bit more complicated. In this case what I ended up doing was translating the NT4 name (DOMAIN\User) to "user principal name" format (e.g. `LogonName@domain.com`). There are a couple different ways to do this. The easiest is probably to use the 3-parameter overload of `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()`, and then grab the value of the `UserPrincipalName` property on the result. Another way would be to use a `DirectorySearcher` and query `LDAP://domain` for the `userPrincipalName` property of the user with the matching `sAMAccountName` value. Note: this solution will only work if all the domains involved are in the same forest.

Comment: According to the answer `Domain\UserName` doesn't work with Negotiate. But how come that when providing `ContextOptions` explicitly in the method call like `context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing)` it works? It's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are validating the user with domain\userName format. You might want to parse the domain name from userName and user the ValidateCredential.