# Could not validate a username and password

Tags: c#, .net

I need to validate that the user inputs are corrects to the current session windows. Thus I use the code below :

```
private void LoginUser(string username, string password)
{
    bool isCredentialValid = false;

    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        isCredentialValid = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
    }
    if (isCredentialValid)
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The problem that I always get false as [`ValidateCredentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889(v=vs.110).aspx) result.

**Rq** : I'm using .Net 4.5 framework

Comment: It's a .Net method

Comment: did you check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363620/principalcontext-validatecredentials-always-returns-false

Comment: Make sure the application has access to the domain with correct credentials

Comment: check whether you are getting any extra characters with your username or password

Comment: @irvgk they are correct, do I need to specify the domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889.aspx

> The ValidateCredentials method binds to the server specified in the
>   constructor. If the username and password parameters are null, the
>   credentials specified in the constructor are validated. If no
>   credential were specified in the constructor, and the username and
>   password parameters are null, this method validates the default
>   credentials for the current principal.

In the PrincipalContext constructor you could specify the credentials you want to check as well.

```
 using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, 
                   container, ContextOptions.SimpleBind, username, password))
{
    return pc.ValidateCredentials(domain + @"\" + username, password,
                               ContextOptions.SimpleBind);
}
```

Try this one.

Comment: Don't use `ContextOptions.SimpleBind` it will send your password with clear text

Comment: @irvgk,No, ContextOptions.SimpleBind means to use Basic Authentication . It does not mean of sending password with cleartext.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and It works even without specifying ContextOptions